# Error while Generating Windows 10 Build in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-10-universal

I have developed a Windows 10 App and when I create App Packages for x86/x64/ARM. It generates .appx package for x86 but for others I get the following error

```
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image' to 'Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls.SuperImage' MCS F:\Company\Windows 10\MCS\MCS\obj\x64\Release\Views\Questions_AnswersPage.g.cs
```

I got the same error at the start but I solved this and after that when I try to generate .appxupload, I get the above error for x64, the build generates successfully for x86.

While generating build, the configuration selected is the following

[image: Configuration]

Can someone suggest, am I doing something wrong? I have one Common project and 2 background Task(Push Notification and Timer)

Comment: Show the xaml for `Questions_AnswersPage`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I have solved this error in g.cs file but it is appearing for x64 and not for x86 build generation.

Comment: Since g.cs file is generated, you should not edit it but fix the XAML instead...

Comment: @Phil1970 I already changed in XAML, but not sure why it gives error in g.cs file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sometimes experiencing similar problems. I always manually rebuild the solution for all (x84, x64, ARM) platforms for *Release* configuration. Then I'm able to successfully generate an *.appxupload* package.

Comment: I will try to do the same. Can you suggest, after this when we generate final package which works on both Desktop and Mobile, do we need select Any CPU? I am doing it for first time for Windows 10.

Comment: Remove AnyCPU from your build definitions. Windows 10 apps are native and managed code is used for debugging only (because it compiles faster).

Comment: Yes but why it takes so much time to generate final .appxupload ?

Comment: It builds the app with all its dependencies to 3 platforms (x86, x64, ARM) with the .NET Native tool chain. You can make it faster by setting *UseDotNetNativeSharedAssemblyFrameworkPackage* to *True* in *.csproj* file. But recently there was a bug in Dev Center that rejected packages generated with this option.